# $_SERVER Variable Syntax Error & Fatal Errors

Tags: php

Even the most basic $_SERVER usage causes Dreamweaver to say there is a syntax error, and actually using it on a live web page ends up causing a fatal error.

I used the following code, straight from the PHP manual, and it causes fatal errors:

```
<?php
echo $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'];
?>
```

I tried a variety of other similar things as well, all with the same result. I even tried assigning some variables using a constructor and the $_SERVER variable, but it didn't matter.

Is there some fundamental piece of information I'm missing about how this works?

Comment: What is the fatal error?

Comment: Is PHP running on your server ?

Comment: 'Dreamweaver' < issue.

Comment: Doesn't list the error, just stops rendering the page half way through. Yes, PHP is running, it's a WordPress website that works fine other than this. Ya, Dreamweaver sucks, I get it.

Update though: the file I'm editing is a plugin file and has some strange scripting. What looked like normal HTML I now realize has random other code in it that's almost psuedo-php. I don't really get what it is but I think that's definitely the issue. $_GET isn't working either.

Comment: Turn on error reporting to show the error message. PHP just doesn't stop running when there's an error. It reports it first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that this particular plug-in PHP file that I was editing was using some sort of strange scripting that I don't recognize. What looked like normal HTML where I could just enter in some PHP was actually the definition of a block of content creating by this strange scripting, which didn't allow any PHP to be used.

Without going into too much superfluous detail, for my purposes I was able to define a variable string in the header before the strange scripting and then output it where I wanted like this:
{$thestring}

Maybe someone else can explain what that is since it's obviously not just normal PHP.